# Как извлечь массив данных нескольких столбцов mysql Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Использую laravel - eloquent и хочу получить массив значений нескольких столбцов без повторений.

Есть таблица продуктов такого вида:

```
id |   title   | category |  brand  |  color  |  stock
1    product 1    phone      apple      red     in-stock
2    product 2    phone     samsung    black    in-stock
```

Чтобы получить все данные из столбца "brand" я делаю так:

```
public static function getAllAvailableAttributes ($category) {
        return static::select(['brand', 'color'])
            ->where([
                ['category', $category],
                ['stock', 'in-stock'],
            ])

            ->distinct()
            ->pluck('brand')
            ->toArray();
    }
```

В итоге получаю что-то подобное:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "apple"
  1 => "samsung"

]
```

Как я могу получить оба столбца одновременно и привести к такому виду:

```
array:2 [▼
   "brand" => array:2 [▼
     0 => "apple"
     1 => "samsung"
   ]
   "color" => array:2 [▼
     0 => "red"
     1 => "black"
   ]
]
```

P.S. Чисто теоретически, я могу поочередно получать эти столбцы методом выше. Но я думаю это нелогично. Столбцов будет много и не вижу смысла каждый раз обращаться к базе данных, а лучше сделать это 1 раз.

Заранее спасибо. Очень надеюсь, что я доступно смог доступно объяснить свою задачу.

Answer (score 1):

group_concat

(SELECT group_concat(distinct(`brand`)) as list FROM `products`) union (SELECT group_concat(distinct(`color`)) as list FROM `products`)

порядковому номеру аргументов соответствует список соответствующей строки DB
разбить строку в массив несложно

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А можно понаглеть и попросить как-то подружить этот вариант решения с моим предложенным кодом? Что-то не могу разобраться. Не потому что не хочу, а не получается =)

Comment: unions - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#unions
raw query - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-expressions
совокупность позволит использовать group_concat и union